# Genymotion Android emulator not starts

Tags: genymotion

I just installed Genymotion and added a virtual machine. When I try to start up the virtual machine using virtual box, It gives the error that is show in the image below. I cannot understand it. Please help me.. I am a Kubuntu 17.04 user.

Virtual Box is showing this while starting the androidemulator

[image: Virtual Box showing this while starting the androidemulator]

Comment: Please reference the link 
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/880479/genymotion-hangs-while-starting-vm-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: No this is not resolving the problem.

Comment: The linked question has an answer with two possibilities. Which one have you tried and with what results.?

Comment: Firstly, I tried the first one to delete the _libdrm.so.2_ file from the installation folder, but it does not exists there. And the second solution was to enable the _propietary drivers_ that I have already enabled. Both the possibilities didn't applied.